# How to Assign a Property to the Class members in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am a Java Guy and Learning Type Script But I came across this situation...!!

I have a Class like

```
export class Human{

    public name: string;
    public surname: string;
    public status:ApprovalStatus(Its an Enum);
  
    constructor( human: Human) {
      Object.assign(this, human);
    }
```

I have a Dialogue of Angular Material where I pass the this Object Human with the values filled for example as name='ABC' and surname='PQR'and status=ApprovalStatus.NOT_APPROVED

The Angular material Dialogue is a separate Component where the Constructor is like

```
openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent,{
    data:{human:this.human},
    disableClose: true });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result)
    });
  }
```

this is how the Dialogue gets Called and I receive the Data back..!!

```
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public human: any,private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>) {}
```

So I will Receive the Data in **human** and now I want to send back the Data by Modifying the Object human like to set the different status from **ApprovalStatus.NOT_APPROVED to ApprovalStatus.APPROVED**

so basically what I am doing is

```
public confirm() {
    let humanData=<Human>this.human;
    human.status=ApprovalStatus.APPROVED;
    this.dialogRef.close({ data: humanData}) // send data to parent component
  }
```

So on the other component I Receive two things separately one is the **status** and other is the **human Object** which is not modified to APPROVED Status not even in the confirm() method anyone point out how to deal with this?

Comment: Without a working stackblitz or something similar, I can't really debug it.  I looked at the docs quickly and whatever you pass as a parameter to the `dialogRef.close()` method should be what is returned in the subscribe.

Comment: Ya thats true but I was passing as a json that was my mistake...!!

Comment: Just remember that while TypeScript gives you some types during coding and compiling, at runtime its JavaScript which has no types.  If you're not getting what you expect, try logging the data and make sure it is actually what you thought it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake when you pass the `human` object to dialog, it should be:

```
openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent,{
        data: this.human,
        disableClose: true
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result)
    });
}
```

so `data: {human: this.human}` should be `data: this.human`.

in your dialog, the data is `{human: this.human}`.
so

```
this.human.status = `xxx`
```

will make the data as:

```
{human: this.human, status: 'xxx'}
```

Comment: I understood my mistake and my work is done but can you elaborate the difference between the two?

Comment: I understood that I was passing the object as a json object instead of the class object thats the only reason if I am not wrong..!!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason in your constructor that you type `human: any` then assert that it's `<Human>` in your component?

I'd update your constructor so its typed properly

```js
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public human: Human,private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>) {}
```

I would think that you code would error too, since you are assigning a value to `human.status` which shouldn't be defined.

```js
public confirm() {
    // this line was not needed, you already have this.human and its not going point to the same object in memory anyway
    //let humanData=<Human>this.human;

    // human is not even defined, so this wont work
    //human.status=ApprovalStatus.APPROVED;

    // we will set the property on the real object this time
    this.human.status = ApprovalStatus.APPROVED;

    // this should have the right data
    console.log('human inside the dialog', this.human);

    // return this.human
    this.dialogRef.close({ data: this.human}) // send data to parent component
  }
```

Comment: Hi @cjd82187 I tried that way but when I do console.log(this.human) its still prints the old status );

Comment: I'm not familiar with what Mat dialog is doing, and how you are getting the data back so I can't comment on that.  Setting a property on an object `someObject.someProperty = someValue` is correct.

Comment: I aded a console log inside the confirm method, human should have the new status you added.

Comment: I just Updated the Question Just I had this Wiered behaviour seen the reason for posting is that only..);